Can't install using terminal
Every time i want to install something i get
Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

And when I enter it , it says Permission denied

What did you enter?  Did you use sudo?  What version of ubuntu are you running?

Use: sudo apt --fix-broken install

(Not just for this question, but) also, plesae see: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask. esp,. the details and context part - which will help you get fast & more relevant/accurate answers.
In general, details like: OS, Software involved in question, System Architecture, etc.

@TalaatEtman yeah I tried that but just said Permission denied

I would like to see the complete error message that follows unmet dependencies in order to confirm or deny that there is some non-standard software source in your software sources that is generating the unmet dependencies error message.

@quill sudo apt install name and I'm on 24.04

I assume that by name you are referring to some as yet unspecified package, but we need to know the exact package name.

@karel It's happens for every package

That reads like there is a problematic software source in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  directory. When you add a PPA source, it usually creates a new file within this directory specific to that PPA. The PPA information goes into this new file.
